# A little C++ help please(repeated output)

Tags: c++

SO i have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int x;
    x=rand();
    int guess;
    do{
        cout<<"Enter your guess:";
        cin>>guess;
        if(guess==x)cout<<"You got it ! ;)\n";
        else {
            cout<<"Wrong(";
            if (guess<x) cout<<"too small)\n";
            else cout<<"too big)\n";
        }

    } while (guess != x);

    return 0;
}
```

question: After compiling and running this program, i enter "999999999999" and it keeps repeating the "too big". why is this so?

additional info: when i set the value of x to constant 10, and i entered 11, i notice it only repeats "too big" once. is there something i am not aware of? or is the code flawed?

many thanks :)

Comment: Integer overflow is my guess...

Comment: A tip for debugging algorithms, instead of using a random number use a specific number. Then you _know_ what the answer is and can test properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [data types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), you will see that an `int` can only hold up to 2,147,483,647<sup>1</sup>. When you try and input a larger number than what your data type can hold than `std::cout` fails and it then tries and process it again in the next loop and that also fails and it sends you in an infinite loop.

You can fix your issue by using a bigger data type.

---

<sup>1</sup> - The size of int depends on your machine, please check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types for the list of ranges that an int can hold

Comment: i fixed it by changing 'int guess;' to 'long int guess'. thanks for your time! much appreciated!

Comment: `int` doesn't have to be 32 bits. It could be 16 and up.

Comment: @chris That is true, but on most machines today it is 32 bits and up. (And writing that down will cause more confusion to the OP and derail from the question)

Comment: I still find it better than lying, which can cause that same lie to be propagated because the OP thinks they're sure it's right. There's bound to be even more confusion when an argument arises because of false beliefs. This comes from experience.

Comment: @chris I put a disclaimer at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting this code to always be successful:

```
cin>>guess;
```

Types derived from `std::ios_base` like `std::cin` may go into an error state.

You can begin to handle this completely by using the stream in a `bool` context.

```
}while (cin && guess != x);
```

Comment: oh i see! thanks alot for the tip ill keep it in mind!

Comment: Putting in a `if(cin)` before or after you pull the data won't help in this case because it won't send it into an error state. You can try it for you self.

Answer (score 1):

If you're curious about exactly what's going on, check out [this cplusplus.com thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/), where someone's having very similar problems reading too-large numbers from `std::cin`.  The second poster, "int main" sums it up very nicely (reformatted a bit for SO):

> `cin.fail()` detects whether the value entered fits the value defined
>   in the variable. But if `cin.fail()` is true, it means that:
>
> - the entered value does not fit the variable
> - the variable will not be affected
> - the instream is still broken
> - the entered value is still in the buffer and will be used for the next `cin >> variable` statement.
>
> Hence you have to do the following:
>
> - repair the instream via `cin.clear()`
> - clear the buffer with `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n')`

I still find this behaviour bizarre and counterintuitive, but at least we know what's happening now.

**Note:** The statement "the variable will not be affected" isn't true, at least for my system (g++ 4.6).  The variable is in fact set to the maximum possible value.  Which makes leaving the entered value on the stream even less explicable...